# Is UITableView scrolled to the top?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I determine if a UITableView is currently at the top of its data? I understand that I could be alerted after a scroll, but I need this for a static UI element rather than a one time triggered event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the current contentOffset with negative value of the adjustedContentInset's top:

```
extension UITableView {
    var isOnTopPosition: Bool {
        contentOffset.y == -adjustedContentInset.top
    }
}
```